# RawPostException: You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream

Tags: json, django, ajax, html-table, raw-post

I am trying to get the data from ajax to django post view, I create the cart with items now I need to get the cart to backend

My js code is:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: "POST",
  data: JSON.stringify({'order_data':order}),
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
  success: function (data) {
    if (data['success']) {
        alert(data['success']);
    }
  },
  error: function (request, error, status) {
    if (request) {

    }
  }
});
```

My View code that I am using in Django view:

```
if request.method == "POST":
  data = json.loads(request.body)
  cart = data['order_data']
```

Then I am getting that error

```
 RawPostException: You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream
```

your suggestions will be preferred

Answer (score 0):

You can get values from POST via:

```
order_data = request.POST.get('order_data')
```

Comment: order_data is not any input field its the dictionary that I creating from jquery and then send it to back, this POST.get give me none

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for it where I need to do the little change in Django view

```
 order_data = json.loads(request.POST.get('order_data'))
```

and my work is done